# Increasing value in a modulo condition with JS

Tags: javascript, html

It doesn't work when I wrote my if condition, I can't increase my money by 100$ every 30 days.

```
<script>
    var money = 100.00; // my initial money
    var rate = 1.0005; // my Interest rate per day (0.05% or 1.0005x)
    for (i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {
        if (i % 30 == 0) { // Each 30 days I add 100$ to my bank
            money += 100.00;
        }
        money = money * rate; // I give money from interest rate
        money = money.toFixed(2); // Round the number
        document.write("Day " + i + " : <strong>" + money + " $ </strong><br>"); // Write for visual purpose
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just did some quick tests, and it looks like the `if (i % 30 == 0)` condition is evaluating to true at the right times, but the `money += 100.00;` line is not doing anything.

Comment: @aj_r: It's doing something, but it's too small to easily see. As the value is a string at that point, the `100` is concatendated at the end of the value so the effect is the same as adding `0.001`. You will get just two more cents in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `toFixed` to convert the value into a string at the end of each iteration.

When you then use the string in the multiplication with the rate it will implicitly be converted back to a number because the multiplication doesn't work with strings. However, when you try to add the hundred each month, the `+=` opreator will do string concatenation instead of addition, so you end up with the value `"101.45100"` instead of `201.45`.

Don't convert the variable `money` into a string, instead put that string in a separate variable for display:

```js
var money = 100.00; // my initial money
var rate = 1.0005; // my Interest rate per day (0.05% or 1.0005x)
for (i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {
  if (i % 30 == 0) { // Each 30 days I add 100$ to my bank
    money += 100.00;
  }
  money = money * rate; // I give money from interest rate
  var m = money.toFixed(2); // Round the number
  document.write("Day " + i + " : <strong>" + m + " $ </strong><br>"); // Write for visual purpose
}
```